# Can't set schema_name in dockerized PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, database-schema, search-path

I'm trying to setup a PostgreSQL Docker Container. I want to create a schema on startup and set `search_path` to that schema.
I've created an initialization .sql file and it's copied to the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder where it's executed by `docker-entrypoint.sh` file on the container's startup. The entrypoint file comes from [the official docker library repo](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/7da010d82077944ce39211cc610ce58c11366360/9.6/docker-entrypoint.sh).
This .sql file contains the following code:

```
CREATE SCHEMA solwa_dev;
SET search_path TO solwa_dev;
-- table creations, sequences, other commands
```

Everything executes properly, but after the initialization completes `search_path` is not setup accordingly. If I type this in a terminal:

```
docker exec -it <docker_container> psql -U postgres -c "show search_path;"
```

it shows `"$user", public"`. After I use the same command to `SET search_path TO solwa_dev;` it still shows both $user and public schemas, but no solwa_dev schema!

Why is this happening and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running `SET search_path ..` will only set the search path for the currently open session.

To set it permanently, you can do so at the role level:

```
ALTER ROLE <role> SET search_path TO ...
```

the database level:

```
ALTER DATABASE <db> SET search_path TO ...
```

or system-wide with the `search_path` [setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-client.html) in postgresql.conf

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875610/permanently-set-postgresql-schema-path) for more details.